# Fabric Texture Magnified

Tags: texturing

I'm new to texturing so I have a jpeg file of a fabric texture and applied it to my cloth. However it seems to be magnified a lot. How do I zoom out or make the fabric texture smaller? When I enlarge the UV map of the cloth on the left I notice its similar to the fabric texture tile

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The texture is just a small section of a piece of cloth, so the UV map of the cloth should be a lot larger than the image. In the UV Editor window on the left scale the shirt UV by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> and dragging the mouse, hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to set the scale.

It also looks like the orientation of the fabric is perpendicular to your UVs. Press <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate, enter "90" for rotating 90° and hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to set the rotation.

The JPEG file should be a tileable texture so that repetition is not so obvious.

Comment: Even after scaling the UV map of the cloth there's not much of a change. Its only when I scale it up so much the whole window is filled is when there's a change. But I'm assuming you can't go past the edges of image?

Comment: You can, it'll just tile.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to blender, what do you mean by 'it'll just tile'?

Comment: Tiling means it repeats the texture. Just be brave, do it and see what happens :-)

Comment: Ok thank you :)